# Iterative proportional fitting with constraints

Tags: estimation, fitting, contingency-tables, log-linear

I am trying to determine if it is possible to conduct iterative proportional fitting with some constraints. To give a dummy example of my goal:

Say I had data for two towns, A and B, on the ice cream purchasing habits of boys and girls:

| Town | Sex | Chocolate cone | Vanilla cone | No ice cream |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Male | 20 | 30 | 10 |
| A | Female | 100 | 30 | 10 |
| B | Male | 10 | 50 | 70 |
| B | Female | 30 | 20 | 40 |

I want to preserve the relationships between variables found in the data but want to apply these relationships to new marginal distributions. For example:

| Town | Sex | Chocolate cone | Vanilla cone | No ice cream | New marginal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Male | 20 | 30 | 10 | 100 |
| A | Female | 100 | 30 | 10 | 200 |
| B | Male | 10 | 50 | 70 | 80 |
| B | Female | 30 | 20 | 40 | 300 |
| New marginal |  | 100 | 400 | 180 |  |

However, I have two other pieces of data I want to preserve: For each of town A and B, I know the total ice cream bought. For example, I know that a total of 200 cones (chocolate + vanilla) were purchased in town A, and 300 were purchased in town B, but I don't know how many of each.

My question is: is there a way to make sure the IPF output conforms to this known total?

Thank you, and I'm sorry if I did something wrong. This is my first time posting on stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\S{\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^3}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
$You can tackle the problem iteratively.

Start with the raw data and the new marginals
$$
M = \m{
20 & 30 & 10 \\
100 & 30 & 10 \\
10 & 50 & 70 \\
30 & 20 & 40 \\}
,\qquad
x=\m{100\\200\\80\\300}
,\qquad
y=\m{100\\400\\180}
$$
and perform *iterative proportional fitting*
$$
M = {\rm ipf}(M,x,y) = \m{
7.76773 & 80.92905 & 11.30322 \\
59.26354 & 123.48897 & 17.24749 \\
1.42600 & 49.52330 & 29.05070 \\
31.54273 & 146.05868 & 122.39859 \\
}$$
Next, define three matrices
$$
A=\m{1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
}
,\qquad
B = \m{
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
}
,\qquad
C = \m{
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
}
$$  and the double-dot product
$$\eqalign{
M:A \,=\, \S M_{ij}A_{ij} \,=\, \S \big(M\odot A\big)_{ij} \\
}$$
in terms of which your extra constraints are $\;A:M=200,\;\;B:M=300$.

Note that $(A,B,C)$ are orthogonal with respect to the double-dot $(:)$ and Hadamard $(\odot)$ products, and idempotent with respect to the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
&A:B \;= 0,\quad&B:C \;= 0,\quad&C:A \;= 0 \\
&A\odot B = 0,\quad&B\odot C = 0,\quad&C\odot A = 0 \\
&A\odot A = A,\quad&B\odot B = B,\quad&C\odot C = C  \\
}$$
Use the Hadamard product to rescale the associated
sub-matrices and enforce the extra constraints
$$\eqalign{
M &= M\odot\LR{\frac{200\,A}{M:A} + \frac{300\,B}{M:B} + C}
 = \m{5.72315 & 59.62738 & 11.30322 \\
43.66454 & 90.98493 & 17.24749 \\
1.87180 & 65.00522 & 29.05070 \\
41.40359 & 191.71939 & 122.39859 \\}
}$$
but now the proportional fitting is wrong, so do it again
$$
M = {\rm ipf}(M,x,y) = \m{
7.42221 & 76.17635 & 16.40144 \\
57.23093 & 117.47554 & 25.29352 \\
1.52160 & 52.05550 & 26.42289 \\
33.82525 & 154.29260 & 111.88215 \\
}$$
then rescale, then refit, then rescale, $\:\ldots\,$ eventually this process converges to
$$\eqalign{
M_* = \m{
5.85211 & 55.98920 & 38.15869 \\
47.42063 & 90.73806 & 61.84131 \\
1.97478 & 62.97797 & 15.04726 \\
44.75249 & 190.29477 & 64.95274 \\
}
}$$
or if you require an integer solution
$$\eqalign{
\biggl\lfloor M_* \biggr\rceil = \m{
6 & 56 & 38 \\
47 & 91 & 62 \\
2 & 63 & 15 \\
45 & 190 & 65 \\
} \\\\
}$$

---

**NB**: $\,$ The process described above assumes that you are using a black-box IPF function.

If you are rolling your own code, then it will be **much** more efficient to enforce the new constraint by appending
an $\,\c{\rm extra}\,$ step to the function's inner loop.

For example, if $(\oslash)$ denotes element-wise division and
$\{u,v\}$ are all-ones vectors the same size as $\{x,y\}$ then
the inner loop of the IPF function would be
$$\eqalign{
&M = M \odot (xv^T) \oslash (M\,vv^T) \\
&M = M \odot (uy^T) \oslash (uu^TM) \\
&\c{M = M\odot\LR{\frac{200\,A}{M:A} + \frac{300\,B}{M:B} + C}} \\
}$$
A single call to the modified function will return $M_*$ directly.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I really appreciate your thorough response, it is so helpful.

Comment: @greg I actually posted a similar question on MathStacked, but instead wondered if we could enforce less defined constraints; for instance, if we know that entries in one columns should be distributed in a given way (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551874/implementing-value-constraints-on-iterative-proportional-fitting-procedure). Could the above readily extend to such cases?